# Dartlang 'await' not waiting?

Tags: asynchronous, dart, async-await

Now I'm really confused with async/await.

My problem (I made some comments into the code) :

```
Future<List<TabEntry>> getLinkStructure() async {
    _log.finest("getLinkStructure called");

    String stringData = await _db.getByKey("structure");
    if (stringData == null) {
        _log.finest("No Structure saved in database - create default structure");
        List<TabEntry> structure = [];
        structure.add(new TabEntry("Home"));

        //All things are working till here

        //Problem: Create key in db - this apparently does not wait 
        String key = await _db.save(serializeToJson(structure), "structure");

        //I EXPECT THE FOLLOWING LOG NEXT

        _log.finest("dbKey: $key");
        if (key == "structure")
            return structure;
        else
            throw "Error while saving default Home tab in structure";
        }

    var data = deserialize(stringData);

    //INSTEAD I GET THIS LOG

    _log.finer("data: ${data}");        
   return data;
}
```

As stated in the source code, I expect to see (in this order):

- getLinkStructure called
- No Structure saved in database - create default structure
- dbKey: structure (will be returned if saving was successful

But instead the last dbkey log i get

- data: INSTANCE OF TabEntry

and then

- `Error with storage initialization: Invalid argument: null`in outer function

**Why does `await _db.save(serializeToJson(structure), "structure")` not wait?**

**EDIT:**

So this is the _db.save function which gets used:

```
@override
Future save(String obj, String key) {
    return _runInTxn((store) => store.put(obj, key));
}
```

And this is _runInTxn(...):

```
Future _runInTxn(Future requestCommand(idb.ObjectStore store),
         [String txnMode = 'readwrite']) async {
var trans = _db.transaction(storeName, txnMode);
var store = trans.objectStore(storeName);
var result = await requestCommand(store);
await trans.completed;
return result;
```

}

Comment: Perhaps `save(...)` (or further down the line some method) makes some async call and doesn't await it (or not properly chain with `.then(...)`?

Comment: hmmm, so, `save(...)` is the method, which should be awaited. So in theory the problem could be that some function inside `save(...)`returns a future but executes it later? So that my await returns, but the inner future has not been run? -> this save function comes from the lawndart library from sethladd.

Comment: `serializeToJson(...)`is a synchronous call, this should not be the problem

Comment: But `_db.save()` itself also can make async calls and return before they are completed.

Comment: Okay, so I added the contents of the _db.save call in my post. But from my perspective, nothing is wrong with that, is it?

Anyways, do you have a good idea how to prevent problems like this, without having to look deep into library code?

Comment: I don't know a better way to find such problems. I also can't find issues in the added code.

Comment: Can you confirm that you do get `No Structure saved in database` first? (as you might get directly `data: INSTANCE OF TabEntry` if stringData is not null. Also can you post your `_db.getByKey`?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not. :( Maybe the problem was, that something failed after that _db.save call at the first time and after that it was not jumping into ìf (stringData == null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the Problem with the await statement disappeared. 
But as I had similar occurrences before, I will watch this in future and see, whether there is some await bug.

You can find further discussion about this problem / about solving the null issue (*) at

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/27469

(*) the null issue: 
 `Error with storage initialization: Invalid argument: null`